# ¿Cómo evitar que un instalador .msi obligue a desinstalar?

Tags: windows-installer

Si creo un setup en formato `.msi` y lo instalo en otro pc la primera vez, bien,
pero si hago algun simple cambio (compilar un `.exe` y ponerlo en el `.msi` sustituyendo al anterior), y lo instalo en el pc donde ya había sido instalado, sale un mensaje diciendo que es necesario desinstalar,

Para colmo el mensaje no ayuda ni dice como ni permite hacer el uninstall automáticamente, el usuario final (a veces muy poco experimentado) debe buscar como desinstalar y luego de desinstalado buscar el `setup.msi`  e instalarlo.

El mensaje que dice es:

> *Ya está instalada otra versión de este producto.  la instalación de esta versión no puede continuar.  Para configurar o quitar la versión existente de este producto, utilice Agregar o quitar programas del panel de Control.*

en ingles:

> *Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel.*

Un poco tedioso.

Esto no solo ocurre con los `.msi` que genero yo, me ha pasado con otros, por lo cual creo que es algo inherente al sistema msi.

Lo que quisiera es que un `setup.msi` simplemente se instale y si hay ya algo instalado que machaque y nada más.

¿Cuál es la mejor forma de que un `setup.msi` se reinstale sin decir nada sobre desinstalar?

Comment: con que herramienta generas el instalador (msi) ? usas algun IDE de desarrollo

Comment: Sumandome a Leandro, podrias decirnos como generas tu archivo msi, ya que sin esa información no te podemos ayudar mucho

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se crea un instalador este tiene asignado un Guid que lo identifica y se ingresa en la registry de windows, sino me equivoco deberia ser aqui

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall[ProductId GUID]

El instalador asigna un Product GUID que lo identifica, cuando se ejecuta por primera vez se registra el Guid en la registry, una siguiente validara que ese guid ya esta presente y mostrara el dialogo uninstall.

Para una instalacion continua deberias regenerar el product guid cada vez que compiles un nuevo msi, aunque cuidado porque si luego revisas en la opcion "Add or Remove Programs", seguramente veas repetido el item del instalador msi.

---

Por ejemplo si usas Wix para crear instaladores puedes configurarlo

[How To: Generate a GUID](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/generate_guids.html)

Si usas el Visual Studio creando un "Setup Project" puedes cambiar el ProductCode

[Updates to setup projects](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/updates-to-setup-projects/)

Aunque me pregunto, no analizaste si la creacion del msi permite crear upgrades?
Lo planteo porque trabajo con el Visual Studio y este incluye una version integrada del InstallShield que permite definir actualizaciones, quizas es el camino que deberias evaluar.

[Doing Upgrades with InstallShield LE](http://syncor.blogspot.com.ar/2013/03/doing-upgrades-with-installshield-le.html)

Comment: Si entiendo bien esto, lo que sugieres es crear un nuevo GUID para hacer creer a Windows de que estás instalando otra aplicación diferente, ¿no?

Comment: exacto, aunque lo recomendado seria que evaluas si la tool que usas permite generar upgrade usando el mismo guid

Comment: Gracias Leandro,
Lo primero que te quiero decir es que he visto que al parecer tienes un negativo, y que yo no he sido (;-)
Ahora estoy intentando usar un instalador que se llama advanced installer, a ver si doy con eso del upgrade que dices, al parecer no se puede si se usa msi, quizá lo mas facil ses generar un setup en formato .exe.

Comment: con que tools generas el .msi ? en mi respuesta mencione varias, deberias ver si la que utilizas lo permite o sin evaluar alguna que lo haga

Comment: Perdona, creia que habia dicho que uso uno que se llama advanced installer (http://www.advancedinstaller.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, para hacer lo que quieres hacer, si es en Visual Studio, tienes que cambiar dentro de las propiedades de tu instalador, donde dice: "RemovePreviousVersions", darle a True, esto permite que se desinstale la versión anterior antes de instalarla, en el mismo proceso.

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias, me es de utilidad conocer esto, pero tambien desinstala y yo quisiera "machacar" sin desinstalar.